# Parse data from XML with namespace

Tags: sql-server, xml-parsing

I'm trying to parse the XML data coming from the SQL Server. But although I tried many ways, I could not succeed.

When I run the script it does not give an error but returns a not record

```
DECLARE @xmlData XML

SET @xmlData = '<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <S:Body>
    <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
      <faultcode>S:VersionMismatch</faultcode>
      <faultstring>Couldnt create SOAP message. Expecting Envelope in namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/, but got null </faultstring>
    </S:Fault>
  </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
'

SET @xmlData = (SELECT @xmlData.query('declare default element namespace "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
/Envelope/Body'))

SELECT @xmlData

SELECT b.value('(./Fault/faultcode/text())[1]', 'Varchar(50)') AS [Name]
  FROM @xmlData.nodes('/Body') AS a (b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `WITH XMLNAMESPACES`:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES('http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' AS S)
SELECT b.value('(./S:Fault/faultcode/text())[1]', 'Varchar(50)') AS [Name]
  FROM @xmlData.nodes('//S:Body') AS a (b);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=811b382e6b2c61023ffb4ed9dcd25afb)**